# Passing a Python argument to a module

Tags: python, python-3.x

Simple NOOB question, but after an hour of searching I still can't find it.  In Python 3.6 I've got a working module nhcparams with a dictionary, FOO.  The following code is tested and works:

```
import nhcparams

def get_max_price():
    my_price = nhcparams.FOO['Price']
```

I'd like to change it to:

```
import nhcparams

def get_max_price(ARG):
    my_price = nhcparams.ARG['Price']

get_max_price(FOO)
```

That doesn't work, which I am hoping is just a syntax problem on my end.  Any help getting me past my idiocy would be appreciated :)

Comment: Where is FOO defined in 2nd code?, and what error you are getting??

Comment: Let me preempt the next question - You probably want to `return` the value (e.g. `return nhcparams.FOO['Price']`) because you won't be able to access `my_price` outside `get_max_price()`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the `getattr` function to dynamically access attributes in your module:

```
import nhcparams

def get_max_price(ARG):
    my_price = getattr(nhcparams, ARG)['Price']

get_max_price('FOO')
```

Notice that 'FOO' needs to be passed as a string. And the attribute is returned from the getattr function call

Comment: Perfect.  Exactly what I needed.  Thank you.  Upvoted, but don't have 15 Rep yet.

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
import nhcparams

def get_max_price(ARG):
    my_price = ARG['Price']
    # Do stuff

get_max_price(nhcparams.FOO)
```

Comment: Did *you* try this?

Comment: @chepner juss changes its typo

Comment: With the edit this is much better. Depending on whether the OP always wants to get the value from `nhcparams` or wants to be flexible about the module then this may or may not be better than the `getattr` method.